# read-only file system on vagrant visualbox ubuntu16.04

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I can't start mysql, nginx service on virtual machine. I am using 5.2.14 r123301 (Qt5.6.2), vagrant, ubuntu16.04.

The following is the log file content generated by visualbox.

Filename: ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log

Content:

```
Welcome to [1mUbuntu 16.04.4 LTS[0m!
...
[   20.145173] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
         Starting Journal Service...
[   20.205086] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[   20.244765] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
         Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   20.360674] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[   20.412384] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
         Mountin[   20.414242] EXT4-fs (sda1): Couldn't remount RDWR because of unprocessed orphan inode list.  Please umount/remount instead
g POSIX Message Queue File Syste[   20.574769] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
m...
[   20.616515] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
         Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   20.619739] systemd[1]: Starting Nameserver information manager...
         Starting Nameserver information [   20.728096] iscsi: registered transport (iser)
manager...
[   20.900808] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
         Starting Create list of required st... nodes for the current kernel...
[   2121790] systd[1]: Cat sice erndSession Slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   21.656083] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Slices.
[ 21046]ysmd1]: arted Forwd ssrdRequesttoallirto Wtch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   22.633045] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
         Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[ 22004]ystemd[1 S uaumount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Set up automount Arbitrary Executab...ats File System Automount Point.
[   23.260962] systemd[1]: Starting Set console keymap...
         Starting Set console keymap...
[   23.098] sstem1]Listeng  /devinctCoatily Named Pipe.

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   24.021547] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   24.044176] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
         Mounting Debug File System...
[   24.2802]ysmd]:isteng n LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[   24.616658] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
         Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors... dmeventd or progress polling...
[   24.672222] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Debug File System.
[   24.680805] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   24.682941] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   24.685020] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Journal Service.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
See 'systemctl status systemd-remount-fs.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load Kernel Modules.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create list of required sta...ce nodes for the current kernel.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Uncomplicated firewall.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console keymap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Nameserver information manager.
         Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
         Mounting FUSE Control File System...
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
         Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
         Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Apply Kernel Variables.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device /dev/ttyS0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors,...ng dmeventd or progress polling.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Starting Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)...
         Starting LSB: AppArmor initialization...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console font and keymap.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories.
See 'systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
See 'systemctl status systemd-update-utmp.service' for details.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: AppArmor initialization.
[   22.700573] cloud-init[580]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   22.813065] [cloud-init[0;1;31mFAILED[0m[580]: ]   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking).

See 'systemctl status cloud-init-local.service' for details.
[   22.813612] cloud-init[580]: [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network (Pre).
    load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.2', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   22.836845] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in main
[   22.838406] cloud-init[580]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   22.839731] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2395, in log_time
[   22.841285] cloud-init[580]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   22.842387] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 603, in status_wrapper
[   22.922651] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m[580]: ]     util.ensure_dirs((data_d, link_d,))Started ifup for enp0s3.

[   22.923260] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1514, in ensure_dirs
[   22.957380] cloud-init[580]:     ensure_dir(d, mode)
[   22.988539]          cloud-initStarting Raise network interfaces...[580]: 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1558, in ensure_dir
[   23.001541] cloud-init[580]:     chmod(path, mode)
[   23.008289] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1780, in chmod
[   23.066402] cloud-init[580]:     os.chmod(path, real_mode)
[   23.067604] cloud-init[580]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/cloud/data'
[   23.069180] cloud-init[580]: Error in sys.excepthook:
[   23.070362] cloud-init[580]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   23.071563] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 145, in apport_excepthook
[   23.137043] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m[580]: ]     os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL, 0o640), 'wb') as f:Started Raise network interfaces.

[   23.137593] cloud-init[580]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_cloud-init.0.crash'[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.

[   23.155457] cloud-init[580]: Original exception was:
[   23.156550] cloud-init[580]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   23.157692] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>
[   23.158935] cloud-init[580]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.2', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   23.186615]          cloud-initStarting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...[580]: 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in main
[   23.248399] cloud-init[580]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   23.339387] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2395, in log_time
[   23.452448] [cloud-init[0;1;31mFAILED[0m[580]: ]     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler).

[   23.600776] cloud-initSee 'systemctl status cloud-init.service' for details.[580]: 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 603, in status_wrapper
[   23.673865] [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network is Online.
cloud-init[580]:     util.ensure_dirs((data_d, link_d,))
[   23.724818]          cloud-init[580]: Starting iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid)...  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1514, in ensure_dirs

[   23.820839] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m] [580]: Reached target Cloud-config availability.    ensure_dir(d, mode)

[   23.849799] [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Initialization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
         Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1558, in ensure_dir
[   23.853858] cloud-init[580]:     chmod(path, mode)
[   23.855295] cloud-init[580]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1780, in chmod
[   23.856992] cloud-init[580]:     os.chmod(path, real_mode)
[   23.858098] cloud-init[580]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/cloud/data'
[   23.860384] cloud-init[969]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   23.861593] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>
[   23.866670] cloud-init[969]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.2', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   23.881856] [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt download activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in main
[   23.971161] [[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to listen on LXD - unix socket.
See 'systemctl status lxd.socket' for details.
[[0;1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for LXD - container startup/shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.
cloud-init[969]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   24.152090] [cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2395, in log_time
[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI Events Check.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.
[   24.152667] cloud-init[969]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   24.356311] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m[969]: ]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 603, in status_wrapperListening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid).
[   24.356932] cloud-init[969]:     util.ensure_dirs((data_d, link_d,))
[   24.570415] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1514, in ensure_dirs
[   24.573723] cloud-init[969]:     ensure_dir(d, mode)
         Starting Login to default iSCSI targets...[   24.584498] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1558, in ensure_dir
[   24.584825] cloud-init[969]:     chmod(path, mode)
[   24.584855] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1780, in chmod
[   24.584889] cloud-init[969]:     os.chmod(path, real_mode)
[   24.584916] cloud-init[969]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/cloud/data'
[   24.584943] cloud-init[969]: Error in sys.excepthook:
[   24.584970] cloud-init[969]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   24.584995] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 145, in apport_excepthook
[   24.585022] cloud-init[969]:     os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL, 0o640), 'wb') as f:
[   24.585048] cloud-init[969]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_cloud-init.0.crash'
[   24.585075] cloud-init[969]: Original exception was:
[   24.585101] cloud-init[969]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   24.585127] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>
[   24.585153] cloud-init[969]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.2', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   24.585180] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in main
[   24.585206] cloud-init[969]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   24.585233] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2395, in log_time
[   24.585295] cloud-init[969]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   24.585357] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 603, in status_wrapper
[   24.585399] cloud-init[969]:     util.ensure_dirs((data_d, link_d,))
[   24.585427] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1514, in ensure_dirs
[   24.585470] cloud-init[969]:     ensure_dir(d, mode)
[   24.585527] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1558, in ensure_dir
[   24.585807] cloud-init[969]:     chmod(path, mode)
[   24.585839] cloud-init[969]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1780, in chmod
[   24.585865] cloud-init[969]:     os.chmod(path, real_mode)
[   24.585893] cloud-init[969]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/cloud/data'

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting LSB: MD monitoring daemon...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Deferred execution scheduler.
         Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started FUSE filesystem for LXC.
         Starting Virtualbox guest utils...
         Starting The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
         Starting MySQL Community Server...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
         Starting Login Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI event daemon.
         Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
         Starting Apply the settings specified in cloud-config...
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
See 'systemctl status redis-server.service' for details.
         Starting Accounts Service...
         Starting Snappy daemon...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Apply the settings specified in cloud-config.
See 'systemctl status cloud-config.service' for details.
[   26.952612] cloud-init[1048]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Advanced key-value store.
[   27.173042] cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Advanced key-value store.

See 'systemctl status redis-server.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Login Service.
[   27.175380] cloud-init[1048]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.2', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   27.364461] cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in main
[   27.404415] cloud-init[1048]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   27.460689] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m[1048]: ]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2395, in log_timeStarted LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: MD monitoring daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Login to default iSCSI targets.
[   27.461093] cloud-init[1048]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   27.672518] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m[1048]: ]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 603, in status_wrapperStopped Advanced key-value store.

[   27.673025] cloud-init[1048]:     util.ensure_dirs((data_d, link_d,))
[   27.884305] [[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
See 'systemctl status redis-server.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1514, in ensure_dirs
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   27.885136] cloud-init[1048]:     ensure_dir(d, mode)
[   28.137014]          cloud-initStarting LSB: automatic crash report generation...[1048]: 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1558, in ensure_dir
[   28.280286]          Starting LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"...
cloud-init[1048]:     chmod(path, mode)
[   28.364385]          cloud-initStarting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...[1048]: 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1780, in chmod
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start A high performance ...rver and a reverse proxy server.
See 'systemctl status nginx.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Virtualbox guest utils.
[   28.418815] [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Permit User Sessions.
cloud-init[1048]:     os.chmod(path, real_mode)
[   28.543257] [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Snappy daemon.
cloud-init[1048]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/cloud/data'
[   28.556827] cloud-init[1048]: Error in sys.excepthook:
[   28.558637] cloud-init[1048]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   28.560950] cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 145, in apport_excepthook
[   28.577498]          Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
cloud-init[1048]:     os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL, 0o640), 'wb') as f:
[   28.595042]          Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Advanced key-value store.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
See 'systemctl status redis-server.service' for details.
         Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
cloud-init[1048]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_cloud-init.0.crash'
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[   28.613164] cloud-init[1048]: Original exception was:
[   28.671524] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m[1048]: ] Traceback (most recent call last):Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand".
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
[   28.671907] cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
[   28.837683] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m[1048]: ]     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.2', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.

[   29.133748] [cloud-init[0;32m  OK  [0m[1048]: ]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in mainStarted Hold until boot process finishes up.

[   29.134233] cloud-init[1048]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   29.484671] [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.
cloud-init[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
See 'systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service' for details.
[1048]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2395, in log_time
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Accounts Service.
[   29.736213] cloud-init[1048]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice User Slice of vagrant.
[   29.836635] cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 603, in status_wrapper
[   30.040488] cloud-init[1048]:     util.ensure_dirs((data_d, link_d,))
[   30.117084] cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1514, in ensure_dirs
[   30.232973] cloud-init[1048]:     ensure_dir(d, mode)
[   30.233252] cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1558, in ensure_dir
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Session 1 of user vagrant.
[   30.233484] cloud-init[1048]:     chmod(path, mode)
         Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
[   30.617319] cloud-init[1048]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1780, in chmod
[   30.809495] cloud-init[1048]:     os.chmod(path, real_mode)
[   30.809779] cloud-init[1048]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/cloud/data'
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Advanced key-value store.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
See 'systemctl status redis-server.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Getty on tty1.
         Starting Set console scheme...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Serial Getty on ttyS0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Login Prompts.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started User Manager for UID 1000.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console scheme.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Advanced key-value store.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
See 'systemctl status redis-server.service' for details.
         Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice User Slice of vagrant.


Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS ubuntu-xenial ttyS0

ubuntu-xenial login: [   57.611598] cloud-init[1693]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   57.611863] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>
[   57.612285] cloud-init[1693]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.2', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   57.612363] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in main
[   57.612437] cloud-init[1693]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   57.612509] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2395, in log_time
[   57.612583] cloud-init[1693]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   57.612655] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 603, in status_wrapper
[   57.612729] cloud-init[1693]:     util.ensure_dirs((data_d, link_d,))
[   57.612801] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1514, in ensure_dirs
[   57.612873] cloud-init[1693]:     ensure_dir(d, mode)
[   57.612944] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1558, in ensure_dir
[   57.613016] cloud-init[1693]:     chmod(path, mode)
[   57.613120] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1780, in chmod
[   57.613233] cloud-init[1693]:     os.chmod(path, real_mode)
[   57.613305] cloud-init[1693]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/cloud/data'
[   57.613377] cloud-init[1693]: Error in sys.excepthook:
[   57.613448] cloud-init[1693]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   57.613520] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 145, in apport_excepthook
[   57.613592] cloud-init[1693]:     os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL, 0o640), 'wb') as f:
[   57.613666] cloud-init[1693]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_cloud-init.0.crash'
[   57.613738] cloud-init[1693]: Original exception was:
[   57.613809] cloud-init[1693]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   57.613881] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>
[   57.613953] cloud-init[1693]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.2', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   57.614024] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in main
[   57.614227] cloud-init[1693]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   57.614315] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2395, in log_time
[   57.614392] cloud-init[1693]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   57.614466] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 603, in status_wrapper
[   57.614541] cloud-init[1693]:     util.ensure_dirs((data_d, link_d,))
[   57.614614] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1514, in ensure_dirs
[   57.614686] cloud-init[1693]:     ensure_dir(d, mode)
[   57.614757] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1558, in ensure_dir
[   57.614829] cloud-init[1693]:     chmod(path, mode)
[   57.614909] cloud-init[1693]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1780, in chmod
[   57.614982] cloud-init[1693]:     os.chmod(path, real_mode)
[   57.615078] cloud-init[1693]: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/cloud/data'
```

How can I fix it? It seems that the system has become read-only.

I tried to create and modify files using the root user, but it also failed.

Answer (score 2):

I found answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942075/error-starting-ubuntu-16-04-lts-read-only-file-system/942078).

I solved the problem with the following command.

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to resolve this error:

From within vagrant `sudo fsck -fy /dev/sda1`

Then exit from the VM, halt it and do `vagrant up` again.